# What's the translation of "bottle-keep" in French?

Tags: traduction, alimentation

Bottle-keep [is a](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bottle_keep&oldid=983767763):

> service which is provided at some Japanese drinking establishments where a patron can purchase a bottle of liquor and have the unfinished portion stored until a later visit. A bottle retained in this manner is called a "keep bottle". The service is offered by a variety of drinking establishments, from casual izakaya to bars in some first-class hotels. For regular customers, the system is less expensive than paying for single drinks. Some restaurants and bars outside of Japan have also adopted the service.

What's the translation of *bottle-keep* in French? Google Translate and DeepL both suggest "garde-bouteille", which makes sense, but I can't find a single use of it in French texts. I recall some nighclub based in France had a bottle-keep bar a decade ago, so there may be some well-established French term for bottle-keep.

I unsuccessfully also tried Linguee:

- https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=Bottle-keep+
- https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=Bottle-keep+bar

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a specific name. On any bar, restaurant or whatever location selling bottles, you are free to ask the waiter to keep a bottle for later use, and they are free to accept or not.

They would generally accept because *le client est roi*.

You would just ask:

> *Vous pouvez mettre notre bouteille de côté pour demain/la semaine prochaine/etc. ?*

If they agree, the waiter marks the level on the bottle, writes your initials on the label and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais : (possibilité de) laisser la bouteille au bar.

Je n'ai pas trouvé d'établissement qui présente ceci comme un service, mais c'est très classique notamment dans les boîtes de nuit où les bouteilles coutent très cher (car le prix de la bouteille sert à payer l'entrée, on dit : *rentrer à la bouteille*).
On peut trouver des allusions à cette pratique dans les [commentaires trip advisor de ce type d'établissement](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Attraction_Review-g196606-d14067042-Reviews-or10-Le_Pulp-Lattes_Montpellier_Herault_Occitanie.html) :

---

I would says : (possibilité de) laisser la bouteille au bar

I did not found any place advertising this service, but it is really commonplace in night clubs where bottles are particularly expensive (they pay for the entrance fee, hence the expression : *rentrer à la bouteille*).
One can find mention of this practice in the [trip advisor commentary section of such clubs](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Attraction_Review-g196606-d14067042-Reviews-or10-Le_Pulp-Lattes_Montpellier_Herault_Occitanie.html) :

> Nous sommes venus au Pulp, en prenant une bouteille de rhum (130 €). N'ayant pas terminé la bouteille, **nous l'avons laissée au bar**. On nous a assuré qu'on pourrait la récupérer lors d'une autre soirée.

> Hier soir nous étions un groupe de 4 amis, nous sommes rentrer à la bouteille pour 120€
> Au cours de la soirée nous avons **rendu plusieurs fois la bouteille au bar avec notre nom** et au bout de la 3ème fois voulant retourner au bar pour nous resservir on nous dit que la bouteille a notre nom à été récupérée (...)